# TouchDown from UIControl Never Called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have changed my view to a UIControl in order to add a TouchDown recognizer (that way I can dismiss isEditing in my UITextView). I have also added an outlet to a function in my class. All my other outlets work, but when I touch down this never gets called. Could it be because my Control has many things layered on top of it? Any other idea why?

[image]
[image]

```
@IBAction func userTappedBackground(_ sender: Any) {
    bioTextView.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Because of top views get all the touch action, so your control can't receive the touch. If you only want to hide keyboard, you can add the gesture to NavigationController.View when keyboard show, and remove it when keyboard hide

Comment: I want to turn of edit mode in textView and this seemed to be the preferred way to do it..?

Comment: You can add a tapGesture to your navigation.view to do it